# zsh ssh-add -L parse error near `-L'

Tags: ssh, zsh

I'm trying to run 
    ssh-add -L
(or any other dashed option), and zsh returns zsh: parse error near `-L'. It's the first time I see zsh do that, and it doesn't do it with any other command.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to find out is whether `ssh-add` is an alias or a shell function, rather than the binary executable `/usr/bin/ssh-add`.

Second, try to run the same command in a ZSH session without your custom ZSH configuration. To get a clean environment, run

```
env -i TERM=$TERM LC_ALL=$LC_ALL LANG=$LANG zsh -f
```

Then try `ssh-add -L` again and let us know what you see.

Moreover, please post the output of the following:

```
uname -a
zsh --version
```

Comment: Alright, thank you. I am an idiot. I added this line in my .zshrc : alias ssh-add='ssh-add || { eval `ssh-agent` && ssh-add }' because I was sick of having to create my ssh-agent when it wasn't here. But it makes my ssh-add incapable of taking command line options. I'll have to think of something smarter. \ssh-add -L worked perfectly.

Comment: If you are running the agent locally on either OS X or Ubuntu, just let the system's own keychain take care of starting the agent for you. You should only have to import every key once. Then you configure which key to be used for each remote host in `~/.ssh/config` (wildcards for hostnames are possible). Finally, to have ssh-agent available on the remote host, add the option `ForwardAgent yes` to those hosts you trust.